# How does one verify state for a mock object?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I have a program Foo that runs on a device and first calls method1() and then method2() on an external module Bar.
When *both* are called, then in response, Bar calls request() on Foo.
To mock Bar, it has a reference to Foo and a method call_Request() which calls foo.request()

```
// in class BarTest
@Test
public void barFlow() {
    InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mockBar);
    inOrder.verify(mockBar).method1(anyInt());
    inOrder.verify(mockBar).method2();
    // what to put as 'thenCallMethod'?
    when(mockBar.method2()).thenCallMethod().call_Request();
}
...
// in class Bar
public void call_Request() {
    foo.request();
}
```

I cannot simply put a call to call_Request() in method2 because only when both methods are called in order does the response happen. Other times, different responses may happen.

**what Mockito trick will do 'thenCallMethod'?**

(I am using the Mockito ver 1.10.19 bundled with Android Studio 2.1)

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use Mockito for this? Mockito can stub and verify `interactions`, but as soon as you mock a stateful collaborator you have to start writing clever and complex InOrder verifications and Answer instances (and so forth). Rather than a `mockBar` it may be much easier to write a `FakeBar` implementation class and inspect its state in the test.

Comment: @JeffBowman Implementing a Fake object would require similar rules which would be read from an xml file. I thought it would be easier with Mockito.implementing all the 'glue'.If this is the most complicated it can get; method1 followed by method2, how can I do it using a Mock object?

Comment: IMHO, a mock object should be able to call methods.

Comment: Do you know about Answer objects?

Comment: @JeffBowman but how would I combine Answer with InOrder?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have no clear definition of what your unit under test is. There seem to be 3 possiblities:

1. there are separate tests for `Foo` and `Bar` and the unit under test is an instance of `Foo` using a mock of `Bar` and an instance of `Bar` using a mock of `Foo`
2. the unit under test is an instance of `Foo` using a real instance of `Bar`, but the `Bar` instance uses a `Foo` mock
3. the unit under test is an instance of `Foo` using a real instance of `Bar` which in turn uses the existing instance of `Foo`

In case 1. you could test the following for `Bar`:

```
@Test
public void testBar1() {
    Foo mockFoo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
    Bar bar = //obtain unit under test that uses mockFoo

    bar.method1(1/*or whatever int value is appropriate*/);
    bar.method2();

    Mockito.verify(mockFoo).request();
}
@Test
public void testBar1() {
    Foo mockFoo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
    Bar bar = //obtain unit under test that uses mockFoo

    bar.method2();
    bar.method1(1/*or whatever int value is appropriate*/);

    Mockito.verify(mockFoo, Mockito.never()).request();
}
```

And the test for `Foo` would look like:

```
Bar mockBar = Mockito.mock(Bar.class);
Foo foo = //obtain unit under test that uses mockBar

// invoke method on foo that would trigger calls to mockBar

InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mockBar);
inOrder.verify(mockBar).method1(anyInt());
inOrder.verify(mockBar).method2();
```

In case 2. you would basically repeat the test for `Foo` from case 1. But you would just verify that `Foo.request()` was invoked on the mock of `Foo` used by the instance of `Bar`. The order of invocations on the `Bar` instance are not of any interest for this test case.

In case 3. you wouldn't be able to verify any invocations, because there are no mocks used at all.

Using something like

```
when(mockBar.method2()).thenCallMethod().call_Request();
```

doesn't make much sense, because you give a mock an implementation, that it might not have in production code.