# How to use Inorder to verify call sequence and then return a value?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, android-testing

The Mockito documentation has [this example](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#in_order_verification)

```
//create an inOrder verifier for a single mock
 InOrder inOrder = inOrder(singleMock);

 //following will make sure that add is first called with "was added first, then with "was added second"
 inOrder.verify(singleMock).add("was added first");
 inOrder.verify(singleMock).add("was added second");
```

How to make it return "ducks in a row"

when add is first called with "was added first, then with "was added second"?

### (assume for example purposes, the List returns a String).

**Update:**

It appears that Mockito cannot handle mocking of states in mock objects. As Jeff Bowman suggested, I had to implement a fake object instead.

I wish that Mockito would be enhanced to allow specification of states. After all, when a compiler generates assembly, Yacc creates a state machine out of our language rules.

@moderator. please cancel the bounty since it cannot be done in mockito.

Comment: FYI: This question is a continuation of the asker's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37847774/1426891).

Comment: @JeffBowman please don't discourage people from answering my question. It is an independent question.

Comment: On the contrary, I'm hoping this will help somebody answer: your previous question makes it clearer what you want, and gives helpful context. You say it's independent but they're clearly related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Mockito cannot handle mocking of states in mock objects. As Jeff Bowman suggested, I had to implement a [fake object](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TheDifferenceBetweenMocksAndStubs) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You are not able to specify return values when using `InOrder`. The use of `InOrder` is restricted to the verification phase of mockitos mocking process. Specifying return values is only allowed in the stubbing phase.

The stubbing phase ends with the first invocation made on the unit under test. After that the verification phase is active.

Comment: I corrected the question to now read, How to make it return "ducks in a row" when add is first called with "was added first, then with "was added second"

Comment: @likejiujitsu there is no method declaration with a return type compatible to `String` in your code example. Therefore the question still seems unclear.

Comment: The LinkedList example does return a String see http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing

Comment: This is an invalid answer.